# Error: Expected Identifier

Tags: c++

So right now I'm just trying to set up a simple class, and can't figure out why I'm getting en error. Here is my header file:

```
#define Mob

class Mob{
private:
    int lvl;
    float hp;
public:
    Mob(int, float); //Error expected an identifier on the float
};
```

and the cpp file with it

```
#include "Mob.h"

Mob::Mob(int level, float health) // Error expected an identifier on the int and float
// and an Error: Expected a ; after the )
{
    hp = health;
    lvl = level;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You defined `Mob` to... nothing. That makes your code equivalent to:

```
class {
private:
    int lvl;
    float hp;
public:
    (int, float); // Expecting an identifier indeed
};
```

and that holds for the rest of the code where `#define Mob` is included.

If you're trying to make include guards, you need a unique name and define it conditionaly:

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_MOB
#define UNIQUE_MOB
// code
#endif
```

Answer (score 16):

This line:

```
#define Mob
```

Causes every instance of the word `Mob` to be replaced with nothing in your code.  Don't do that.

It looks like you wanted to make an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), which should look something like:

```
#ifndef MOB_H
#define MOB_H


  ...

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know everything that exists in C++ directives are known as entities except Processor directives(e.g macro , symbolic constants etc)
and about pointers keep it in mind that for ease of applying them , imagine them as integer variables whose duty is keeping the address of memory storage locations
this is good hack in the level where you are learning about pointers for the 1st time

Answer (score 0):

First you can delete `#define mob`. All you have to do is `#pragma once` to avoid the .h file to get included twice. As I can see here you have two files one called mob.h and mob.cpp. Instead of having two different files you can have it in one file just mob.h like in the code below and since you only initialize the variables in the constructer you can use the : operator between the () brackets and {} brackets. The variable name before the brackets in `lvl(level)` is the variable defined in your class and the one inside the brackets is the one from the function.

```
#pragma once

class mob
{
private:
    int lvl;
    float hp;
public:
    mob(int level, float health)
        : lvl(level), hp(health) {}
};
```